# How to resolve a ng-model variable from angularJS in ejs template

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs, angular-ngmodel

I am using MEAN stack.
I have set my templating engine as **'ejs'**,
and now when i try to attach an ng-model, it is not getting resolved in the ejs template.

Things tried till now:

- tried using html template(and then used '{{' '}}'), but did not work
- in ejs template used '<%=' '%>', with no result

Code for **index.ejs** is given below

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

      <title>HOME</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
        <input ng-model="name"> Hello <%= name %>
  </body>
  </html>
```

How to get **name** resolved in **ejs** template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason to use ejs along with angular really.  Let angular handle the templating and binding data in the view, setup your server side components (express, mongo, and node) to act as an API that uses JSON objects to communicate the request and response body.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  {{name}}
</div>
```

Perhaps you're just missing your ng-app?

Comment: so then what is the engine i should set in app.js?
`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, it still doesnt resolve **name**. I think i will have to use an html template. should i?

Comment: @dreamer haven't used express myself or ejs but you just need to be sure your server side templating isn't removing the {{}} what I wrote here is just the client side code and it works fine as is.

Comment: Just as a general rule it's better if your API isn't doing things to the template and is responsible for fetching/posting data.  This keeps your client from depending on a particular server side implementation or your server code from only working with one particular type of client consumer (what if you want a native app in the future or want to change your backend technology)

Comment: If you are really set on having both server side and client side templating then you can use the $interpolateProvider to setup the start and end symbol for angular to look for if it conflicts with the symbols used in your server side templating.

Answer (score 0):

try this on template...

```
<% if(name){ %>
  <script>
  window.name= <%- JSON.stringify(name) %>;
  </sript>
<% } %>
```

try on your controller..

```
$rootScope.name = window.name;
console.log($rootScope.name);
```